# FFmpeg: Add alpha channel to a video using a PNG mask

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg, alpha, blend

I saw that FFmpeg can merge/blend two videos with alpha channel and can encode video with alpha channel using the `qtrle` codec, but, It is possible to apply a PNG file mask, either a black and white or a PNG with an alpha channel to a video in order to have a video with the alpha channel of the PNG applied?

Here is the concept in images

Original video:
[image: Original video]

PNG file with alpha channel, the "mask":
[image: PNG file with alpha channel]

And the result:
[image: Result]

Or even a black and white image as a mask for alpha channel:
[image: bnw image]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Use the `alphaextract` and `alphamerge` filters:

```
ffmpeg -i video -vf "movie='image',alphaextract[a];[in][a]alphamerge" -c:v qtrle output.mov
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked for one frame, but your settings give me the understanding, so here is the command that worked:
`ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -loop 1 -i mask_with_alpha.png -filter_complex "[1:v]alphaextract[alf];[0:v][alf]alphamerge" -c:v qtrle -an output.mov`

Comment: Hi. I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951088/writing-alpha-channel-into-decoded-ffmpeg-frame
What is the programmatic way to do this ?

Comment: Did you use the mask file or the black and white file , I couldnt quite get the output you have got

Comment: I was attempting to mask off an already-transparant video, and it required blending together alpha channels. Adding another `alphaextract` filter and setting a `blend` filter to `darken` did the trick: `-filter_complex "[1:v]alphaextract[alf];[0:v]alphaextract[oalf];[alf][oalf]blend=all_mode=darken[res];[0:v][res]alphamerge"` Doing this removes the need for `-loop 1` on the input.

Comment: How to do the same just for single image?