# Writing alpha channel into decoded ffmpeg frame

Tags: c, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am looking for a fast way to add my own alpha channel to a decoded ffmpeg frame.

I have an AVI file with RGB information, and I have a synchronized video stream describing the transparency alpha channel (grayscale). While decoding the AVI file using ffmpeg, I want to convert the output frame to RGBA, while adding my own alpha information. In the end, I would obtain a semi-transparent video stream.

Is there any optimized function, maybe in libswscale or libswresample, to do such a thing better than just iterating through pixels ?

Basically I would like to be able to write such a function, if only I had such a function as **sws_scale_and_add_alpha**:

```
void* FFmpegLib_nextFrame_withAlpha(void* _handle, uint8_t* my_alpha_channel)
{
    FFmpegLibHandle* handle = (FFmpegLibHandle*)_handle;
    AVPacket        packet;
    int             frameFinished;

    while(av_read_frame(handle->pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0) {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if(packet.stream_index==handle->videoStream) {
            // Decode video frame
            avcodec_decode_video2(handle->pCodecCtx, handle->pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
            // Did we get a video frame?
            if(frameFinished) {
                sws_scale_and_add_alpha
                (
                    handle->sws_ctx,
                    (uint8_t const * const *)handle->pFrame->data,
                    handle->pFrame->linesize,
                    0,
                    handle->pCodecCtx->height,
                    handle->pFrameARGB->data,
                    handle->pFrameARGB->linesize,
                    my_alpha_channel
                );

                return handle->pFrameARGB->data;
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've thought about two ways to do this. Usually if I want to merge a alpha channel in command line, `ffmpeg` provides an `alphamerge` filter for this. And I'm pretty sure you can do the same thing in C, though it may be difficult to program, (even there is a video filter example in ffmpeg source.).

The second is just coding it ourselves, against AVFrame structure. The `data` field of AVFrame holds the pixels info. We need to pack our alpha channel into it.

First convert compressed image frame to packed ARGB as usual

```
// pFrameARGB should have been allocated and of pix_fmt `AV_PIX_FMT_ARGB`
sws_scale(sws_ctx, pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, height, pFrameARGB->data, pFrameARGB->linesize);
```

AVFrame.data is a multi-dimension array contain different planes. Here we have a packed ARGB image, not a planar one, so that `data[0]` contains all pixels we need.

```
// cpp example, easy to convert to pure C
auto p = pFrameARGB->data[0];
for (auto i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    auto num = i * sizeof(uint8_t) * 4;
    auto div_result = std::div(num, width * sizeof(uint8_t) * 4);

    auto offset = pFrameARGB->linesize * div_result.quot + div_result.rem;
    p[offset] = my_alpha_channel[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @halfelf. I saw the alphamerge example and even sneaked into the c implementation. It is a bit like your second programming option actually, as it loops through the argb image pixels. I was hoping, for performance reasons, to do it in one shot, like using a replacement for sws_scale that would convert and add the alpha channel at the same time. Actually in the end, I'm using the rgb and alpha channels as a texture for an OpenGL shader, so it looks like the best and most parallel option is to combine color and transparency inside the shader.

Comment: @Mic Good to hear that. Actually I've done similar things in CUDA before. I believe its performance is as good as OpenGL.